# Can only add a C# Class to a VB.Net project

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

I just installed VS 2017 a couple of days ago.

Normally I work in C#.

However, I have one project that was written in VB.Net.

I want to pull out a selection of VB procedures and functions and put them in a static class.

However, when I try to add a new Class to the project it only gives me the option of a C# class, no VB at all.

Yes I could convert the VB code to C# but that is a lot of work and I don't want to do it since I shouldn't have to.

Has anyone encountered this and if so did you find a solution?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you trying to add a new class?  Are you sure the Tree menu is not in the `Visual C#` category...

Comment: If you just use the "add C# class" but then rename the file to `Foo.vb` and write VB in it, does that work?

Comment: Did you make sure to add all the pieces parts needed to do VB programming?  The new installer lets you piecemeal everything.

Comment: I am using the Add menu item from right clicking on the project.

Comment: I installed the defaults for VS 2017 Professional.  I can create a new VB Project and add new VB classes to that.

Answer (score 0):

C# and VB.Net can coexist in the same solution, but not the same project.  You can add a second project to your solution.  Make it a VB.Net class library.  Add any VB.Net modules to the new class library.  Add a reference in your C# project to the VB.Net class library.  Build all and enjoy!

If you do decide to translate from VB.Net to C# to keep things cleaner, I have had good luck with the code translator found here: http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: Actually I believe you can (I am pretty sure I've done it).  However, that isn't my issue, my issue is that it is forcing me to add a C# class to at VB project.  I don't want to do that.

Comment: Sorry, I should have inferred that from the title of the post - I thought you were trying to pull old VB code into a new C# project.  My only thought is that maybe the project upgrade wizard did something funny... In Windows file manager, check the extension of the project file to see if it is a .csproj file or a .vbproj file (it should be a .vbproj, but then again it should let you add VB classes, so maybe it won't be.)  Also, can you build the code as is (before adding the class), or does the compiler throw a million errors?

Comment: Yes that seems to be the problem.  Yes the project compiles fine.

Comment: Does anyone know of a converter that will change a CS project file to a VB project file?

Comment: How much actual work has been done to the project properties?  If it is a relatively new project, it may be easiest to start a new project, and just "Add Existing Items" to copy in any files that contain your code.  If this is production software, it might be more complicated than that...

Comment: I have played around a bit trying to convert one to the other with a text editor - simply renaming from .vbproj to .csproj breaks the solution, and I haven't had any luck so far copying missing sections from one to the other.  I doubt there is a converter available, because the assumption would be that a .csproj contains a bunch of C# files that wouldn't compile if you changed the project structure to .vbproj.